# Magento 2 : Need Slider on Page Other Than Homepage

Tags: magento2, development, page

I want to add slider on magento page and want to remove breadcrumb from other than homepage.

Any body can advice how can I add slider to page other than homepage, and how can I remove breadcrumb from just one page..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove breadcrumb from any particular page then you need to do the following things.

- You need to identify the xml file of that page. It is avilable here.

  > app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Vendor_Extension/layout/your_custom_page.xml
- Add the following code into that file.

  ```
      <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
  ```
- Remove **var/cache** and **var/page_cache** folder.